# Visual Studio IDE layout tips

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I've never found an "ideal" layout for coding in Visual Studio. I have a three-monitor setup, but it seems that the solution explorer/properties/output/errors/whatever panes are always getting in the way or hogging screen space. It's a bit open-ended, sure, but do you have an "ideal" layout with the myriad of floating/dockable/anchored setups for specific windows? For instance, I like to split vertical code panes between two screens, and typically the solution explorer is anchored to the right of the right-most code pane, but that chews up screen real estate that I'd rather have for the code. I was thinking of floating those sorts of things off to another screen.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently VS 2010 will do a LOT more for multi monitor setups. ScottGu went over this at DevConnections 2008, and a few more times, usually wherever he goes.

I got the impression that the MDI or tabbed codefiles might be able to be detached from the IDE, and float/draggable onto another monitor.

As it stands today in VS 2008, Solution Explorer, Immediate Window, etc are detachable and be able to float onto another monitor, separate from the main IDE.